# Create Navigation with offline Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I was just wondering as to how to download/create a map out of Google Maps in order for it to work offline.

I was thinking of creating a navigation system with offline Google Maps, but I don't know how to get a copy of Google Map to work offline then embed it with my own application.

Please help me on this one.. really need it badly...

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html

Please read section 10.1.3

Downloading and creating a derivative work is against the terms of service.

Comment: So can't we implement offline navigation in android application? Is there any way to implement offline navigation and tracking in Android application ?\

Answer (score 0):

it is already builtin i think ? 
google maps has now a local cache for maps , still not sure what we can do with it

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6sNyKzGOe8